# Html text box only refreshes on click when changing its value from script?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to implement an autofill function and I got pretty far but now I'm stuck. I want to automatically fill the textbox if there are more than 4 characters with the data recieved from backend but the code only does this when I click away. Thank you for your help!

The html:

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" id="myText" onchange="autoFill()" />
```

And the ajax:

```
function autoFill() {
        if (document.getElementById("myText").value.length > 4) {
            var data2send = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("myText").value);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost:44348/api/values/CheckDatabase',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data2send,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    document.getElementById("myText").value = data;
                },
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `onkeyup`  event instead of `onchange`. Then it will work.

Comment: It would be really appreciated if you can accept it as well :)

Comment: 4 more minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try to change the event to an oninput event, like so:

```
<input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" id="myText" oninput="autoFill()" />
```